# React-Native call function inside .then async function

Tags: react-native, promise, react-native-camera

I am trying to call a function after the user has taken a picture. I try to do so in the following way:

```
export default class LA extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.doSomething = this.doSomething.bind(this);
    }


    takePicture() {
      this.camera.capture()
      .then(function(data) {
        doSomething(data.path); //THIS CAUSES THE RUNTIME ERROR
      })
     .catch(err => console.error("error: " + err));
    }

    doSomething(imgPath) {
      console.log(imgPath);
    }


}
```

And I get the following error when taking a picture:

> error: Reference Error: doSomething is not defined

However, If I replace takePicture() with:

```
takePicture() {
  this.camera.capture()
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data.path);
  })
 .catch(err => console.error("error: " + err));
}
```

The image path is logged, and no error occurs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `this` in order to call a member function. Here's a working example:

```
export default class LA extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.doSomething = this.doSomething.bind(this);
  }


  takePicture() {
    this.camera.capture()
    .then((data) => {
      this.doSomething(data.path);
    })
   .catch(err => console.error("error: " + err));
  }

  doSomething(imgPath) {
    console.log(imgPath);
  }


}
```

Note that I've used an arrow function to reference the correct `this` inside the callback.

Or you can also pass the function directly, like this.

```
  takePicture() {
    this.camera.capture()
      .then(this.doSomething)
      .catch(err => console.error("error: " + err));
  }
```

However, the last approach will not run `doSomething` on the correct scope, for that you will need to bind `doSomething` to the class, using an arrow function or in the constructor using `bind`. A third option is to use a decorator to autobind the method using Babel.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
export default class LA extends Component {

  ...


  takePicture1() {
    this.camera.capture()
    .then((data) => {
      this.doSomething(data.path);   // CORRECT
      // keyword `this` represents instance of class LA
    })
   .catch(err => console.error("error: " + err));
  }


  takePicture2() {
    this.camera.capture()
    .then(function (data) {
      this.doSomething(data.path); // WRONG
      // function defines `this` as the global object 
      // (because it's where the function is executed)
    })
   .catch(err => console.error("error: " + err));
  }

  doSomething(imgPath) {
    console.log(imgPath);
  }
}
```